# How can I validate the root DNS key-signing-key on the command line?

Tags: dns, dnssec

Consider the following `dig` command and its truncated output:

```
dig . dnskey +dnssec +multi @a.root-servers.net
...
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
.                       172800 IN DNSKEY 257 3 8 (
                                AwEAAaz/tAm8yTn4Mfeh5eyI96WSVexTBAvkMgJzkKTO
                                iW1vkIbzxeF3+/4RgWOq7HrxRixHlFlExOLAJr5emLvN
                                7SWXgnLh4+B5xQlNVz8Og8kvArMtNROxVQuCaSnIDdD5
                                LKyWbRd2n9WGe2R8PzgCmr3EgVLrjyBxWezF0jLHwVN8
                                efS3rCj/EWgvIWgb9tarpVUDK/b58Da+sqqls3eNbuv7
                                pr+eoZG+SrDK6nWeL3c6H5Apxz7LjVc1uTIdsIXxuOLY
                                A4/ilBmSVIzuDWfdRUfhHdY6+cn8HFRm+2hM8AnXGXws
                                9555KrUB5qihylGa8subX2Nn6UwNR1AkUTV74bU=
                                ) ; KSK; alg = RSASHA256 ; key id = 20326
```

The ICANN website lists [multiple different hashes](https://www.iana.org/dnssec/files) in the `root-anchors.xml` file and the two PDFs with physical signatures.

I attempted to run `sha256sum` directly on base64-decoding of the above DNSKEY record and got `d6b602bc8f107abe8e9b68c2d0afbfe1ca655767063b1d20c31a6398f3521d2e`, which does not match any of the hashes as far as I can tell.

**What set of commands can I run on output of the dig command to get or verify any or all of the hashes listed on the ICANN website?**

Comment: This question was originally asked on Stackoverflow, and someone suggested that I move it here. If there is a better home for it, please let me know in the comments!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75728842/how-can-i-validate-the-root-dns-key-signing-key-on-the-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RFC 4034 specifies in [section 5.1.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4034#section-5.1.4) how the digest field in DS records is computed:

```
   The digest is calculated by concatenating the canonical form of the
   fully qualified owner name of the DNSKEY RR with the DNSKEY RDATA,
   and then applying the digest algorithm.

     digest = digest_algorithm( DNSKEY owner name | DNSKEY RDATA);

      "|" denotes concatenation

     DNSKEY RDATA = Flags | Protocol | Algorithm | Public Key.
```

The wire format of DNSKEY records is specified in [section 2.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4034#section-2.1) of the same RFC:

```
   The RDATA for a DNSKEY RR consists of a 2 octet Flags Field, a 1
   octet Protocol Field, a 1 octet Algorithm Field, and the Public Key
   Field.
```

The encoding of domain names is specified in [section 3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035#section-3.1) of RFC 1035:

```
Domain names in messages are expressed in terms of a sequence of labels.
Each label is represented as a one octet length field followed by that
number of octets.  Since every domain name ends with the null label of
the root, a domain name is terminated by a length byte of zero. […]
```

Putting all of this together, we have to concatenate the following data:

- `\x00`: the wire format of the root zone
- `\x01\x01`: 257 in the [flags field](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4034#section-2.1.1)
- `\x03`: 3 in the [protocol field](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4034#section-2.1.2)
- `\x08`: 8 in the [algorithm field](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4034#section-2.1.3)
- the public key in binary

[root-anchors.xml](https://data.iana.org/root-anchors/root-anchors.xml) lists 2 as the digest type for the key with the id/tag 20326:

```
<KeyDigest id="Klajeyz" validFrom="2017-02-02T00:00:00+00:00">
  <KeyTag>20326</KeyTag>
  <Algorithm>8</Algorithm>
  <DigestType>2</DigestType>
  <Digest>E06D44B80B8F1D39A95C0B0D7C65D08458E880409BBC683457104237C7F8EC8D</Digest>
</KeyDigest>
```

According to [this list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ds-rr-types/ds-rr-types.xhtml), this means that we have to hash the above data with SHA-256.

When we paste the following into a shell, we get the desired result:

```
$ { echo -en '\x00'; echo -en '\x01\x01'; echo -en '\x03'; echo -en '\x08'; echo 'AwEAAaz/tAm8yTn4Mfeh5eyI96WSVexTBAvkMgJzkKTOiW1vkIbzxeF3+/4RgWOq7HrxRixHlFlExOLAJr5emLvN7SWXgnLh4+B5xQlNVz8Og8kvArMtNROxVQuCaSnIDdD5LKyWbRd2n9WGe2R8PzgCmr3EgVLrjyBxWezF0jLHwVN8efS3rCj/EWgvIWgb9tarpVUDK/b58Da+sqqls3eNbuv7pr+eoZG+SrDK6nWeL3c6H5Apxz7LjVc1uTIdsIXxuOLYA4/ilBmSVIzuDWfdRUfhHdY6+cn8HFRm+2hM8AnXGXws9555KrUB5qihylGa8subX2Nn6UwNR1AkUTV74bU=' | openssl base64 -d; } | openssl sha256
e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
```